# How to display the elements of a returned list in Roxygen?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I can do this easily with input parameters by having multiple lines of `@param` by doing as such:

```
#' @param var1 This is for x
#' @param var2 This is for y
#' @param var3 This is for Z
```

But how do you do that for the elements of a list you are returning. I want to include the names of each element and a description about them. Chaining together `@return` or `@param` does not have the same behavior. What is the appropriate tag?

```
#' @return A list with the following elements:
#' @something element1 Contains x
#' @something element2 Contains y
#' @something element3 Contains z
```

The package `samr` has the exact markdown formatting I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the documantation - http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting

@return Used to document the object returned by the function. For lists, use the `\item{name a}{description a}` describe each component of the list.

Comment: That did it. I was using `\itemize` and that was changing the formatting.

Answer (score 15):

Since the link was broken in the accepted answer, I included a simple example of `roxygen` documentation for a function that provides a list as a return value.

```
#' Sample function that returns a list and uses roxygen documentation.
#'
#'
#' @return A list with letters and numbers.
#' \itemize{
#'   \item A - The letters of the alphabet.
#'   \item B - A vector of numbers.
#' }
myfunction <- function() {
  list(
    A = LETTERS,
    B = 1:10
  )
}
```

Assuming your package is called `mypackage`, the above facilitates producing documentation similar to the output below when running `?mypackage::myfunction`.

[image]

This was based on the link to [R packages - Object Documentation - Text formatting reference sheet](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting)

Comment: The lists will not be aligned nicely, if the items are in different length. item{name a}{description a} is better in that case.

Comment: @ccshao Thanks, I will add that option when I have a little more time to test my solution.